# Destroy a freewall instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the [jquery-Freewall-plugin](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) and i want to know how to destroy an instance of it.

I wrote a little example for you people to understand:

```
var startFreewall = function(){
    $(function() {
        var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
        wall.reset({
            selector: '.brick',
            animate: false,
            cellW: 160,
            cellH: 160,
            delay: 50,
            onResize: function() {
                wall.refresh($('div.col.rood.bart').width()+100, $('div.col.rood.bart').height()+100);
            }
        });
        // caculator width and height for IE7;
        wall.fitZone($('div.col.rood.bart').width()+100 , $('div.col.rood.bart').height()+100);
    });
}
startFreewall();

$('button').click(function(){
    'destroy the function so i can call it again'
});
```

Comment: I think `$('#freewall').freewall('destroy')` or `$('#freewall').destroy()` should get you there if placed in your click handler.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: Yup. Some docs to back you up: https://github.com/kombai/freewall/commit/ba7b17c3985a4cb25ad9c43f1c17f7e5301eefbd

Comment: Yes nice one @CaseyFalk.

Comment: Can the draggable function destroy at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s how to remove all instances of all plugins from an element if the plugin does not include a destroy method:

```
$.removeData($element.get(0));
```

This will not remove the bound events. You have to do that separately.
If the plugin you’re trying to remove has namespaced events, you’re in luck:

```
// Remove namespaced events added using .on()
$element.off('pluginNamespace');
// Remove namespaced events added using .bind()
$element.unbind('.pluginNamespace');
```

If not, you can examine all of the events attached to an element:

```
console.log(
    '$element events:', 
    $._data($element.get(0), 'events')
);
```

Here’s all wrapped up in a handy function:

```
var destroyUnwantedPlugin = function($elem, eventNamespace) {
    var isInstantiated  = !! $.data($elem.get(0));

    if (isInstantiated) {
        $.removeData($elem.get(0));
        $elem.off(eventNamespace);
        $elem.unbind('.' + eventNamespace);
    }
};
```

You need to pass the instance to above function:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    destroyUnwantedPlugin(wall);
});
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: @user3918528, are you fine with the answer?

Comment: @user3918528, have you got your answer?

Comment: Welcome :) user3918528. Don't mind you can also upvote for the answer :P