# Destroy “freewall” jquery plugin draggable function after clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Currently I'm using freewall plugin to build my grid view page (http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) HOwever, there is a function to switch the grid view to listing view so that I'd like to destroy the function and make my div clean.

Found the question asked here: [Destroy a freewall instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183726/destroy-a-freewall-instance)

At which, the answer in this question is:  $('#freewall').freewall('destroy') or $('#freewall').destroy()

How do I remove the draggable function after button clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the firewall instance's properties. For this you need to use 
`reset()` method and set `draggable` (boolean property) to false on button click.

For eg:

**Your firewall instance:**

```
var wall = new freewall('.free-wall');
```

**The button click handler:**

```
$("button").click(function(){
   wall.reset({
      selector  : '.brick',
      draggable : false        //remove element's draggable property
   });
});
```

Please refer to [**link**](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/#options) for more details

Comment: Or if you want to destroy its instance then, please refer to my answer in post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183726/destroy-a-freewall-instance/25736891#25736891